# How to access selected option in Angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two selects, the contents of second must depends on selected value at first select. E.g. I want to load list of companies (to 2nd `<select>`) which providing particular service (selected in 1st `<select`>):

```
<div ng-controller="GetCompaniesByService as class">
    <select ng-options="service.name for service in class.services"  ng-model="selectedService"></select> 
    Chosen service_id: {{ selectedService.id }}
    <select ng-options="company.name for company in class.companies"  ng-model="selectedCompany"></select> 
  </div>
```

How to access in controller current selectedService.id value from model?
Е.g I need to dynamically load data via ajax, from url like this

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/service/'+selectedService.id)
```

to use it in second `<select>`

Comment: Try: `$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/service/'+ $scope.services[$scope.selectedService].id)`

Comment: got error in console: `$scope is not defined`

Comment: how is structured your controller?, put your controller script

Answer (score 0):

you have to watch for selectedService in your controller scope. First initialize the value of selectedService to "false", then when the user will change the option selectedService will get the value of the select.

Once the value of selectedService became different from "false" show the second select/option.

your html :

```
<div ng-controller="GetCompaniesByService as class">
    <select ng-options="service as service.name in class.services"  ng-model="selectedService"></select> 
Chosen service_id: {{ selectedService.id }}
    <select ng-options="company as company.name in class.companies"  ng-model="selectedCompany" ng-show="selectedService"></select> 
</div>
```

your controller :

```
app.controller('GetCompaniesByService',function($scope){
    $scope.class = {};                  //initialize the class object
    $scope.class.services = [...];      //your first $http request
    $scope.selectedService = false;
    $scope.class.companies = function(){
        if(selectedService){
            return $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/service/'+selectedService.id)
             .success(function(data){return data;})
             .error(function(error){return [];});
        }
        else{
            return [];
        }
    };
});
```